# Trouble With Java GUI Error

Tags: java, swing, exception

This program is supposed to convert the miles entered by user and convert to kilometers using GUI interface. Program currently does not compile.

aaaaa.java:10: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public CalcPanel() {
           ^
   1 error

Wherever I look for examples of this type of program I see no return type with that method. Any ideas? Thanks

Here is the program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class aaaaa extends JFrame {
private JLabel messageLabel= new JLabel("Enter distance in miles");
private JTextField milesTextField = new JTextField(10);;
private JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate"); 

public CalcPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(messageLabel);
    panel.add(milesTextField);
    panel.add(calcButton);

    calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new CalcPanel();
        frame.setTitle("M to Km Converter");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
}

class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = milesTextField.getText();
        double kilometers = Double.parseDouble(input) * 1.6023;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + " miles is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
    }
}
}
```

So that problem was solved but here is another. The panel pops open but my messageLabel milesTextField calcButton do not show up.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class Aaaa extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel messageLabel= new JLabel("Enter distance in miles");
    private JTextField milesTextField = new JTextField(10);;
    private JButton calcButton = new JButton("Calculate"); 

    public Aaaa() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(messageLabel);
        panel.add(milesTextField);
        panel.add(calcButton);
        setVisible(true);
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new Aaaa();
            frame.setTitle("M to Km Converter");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setSize(300, 150);
    }

    class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener {        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input = milesTextField.getText();
            double kilometers = Double.parseDouble(input) * 1.6023;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + " miles is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why'd you change the name of the class?  Chances are, if this *is* an assignment, and you may get in trouble for it, you'd be found out from the body of the code instead...

Comment: The class must be named after "The Castle of Aaaauuuggghhhh". That's where the pure of spirit may find the holy grail.

Comment: So I went ahead and rolled this back, as it would make your existing answers look extremely weird.  If you have another question to ask, feel free to do so; however, I **strongly** encourage you to do some investigation of this on your own before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a typo error, the class and constructor names are not matching. Your class name is aaaaa while your constructor name is CalcPanel.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to create a constructor, but the name of the constructor doesn't match the name of the class.

Change `public CalcPanel` to `public aaaaaa` instead.

Comment: this worked well. knew it was something as simple as that however i have a new error...    aaaaaa.java:24: error: non-static method setVisible(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context
   setVisible(true);
   ^
1 error

Comment: That's an implementation problem - you're attempting to run an inherited, non-static method in `main`.  You'll have to move the declaration of that into the actual class, and not in `main`.